# How convert to NaT into NaN in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, converters

I have dataframe like below

```
df.head(3)

ORD     Date1                   Date2           
717 2020-03-04T00:00:00Z    2020-03-04T00:00:00Z
722 NaT                     2020-03-15T00:00:00Z
719 2020-05-14T00:00:00Z    NaT
```

I want to convert all NaT to NaN

**Expected Output**

```
ORD   Date1                   Date2           
717 2020-03-04T00:00:00Z    2020-03-04T00:00:00Z
722 NaN                     2020-03-15T00:00:00Z
719 2020-05-14T00:00:00Z    NaN
```

How can this be done

Comment: @aepaen, I was about to post the same question . I also waiting for the answer

Comment: Why you need this? I believe NaT have the same behavior as NaN.

Comment: @Terry, I have below of code which accepts only `NaN` . I need to convert this `NaT`

Comment: you can do it only if you changing the column type and lost all the `datetime` functions

Comment: @Terry, i am ok convert this to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously in pandas not necessary, because `NaT` are processing like `NaN`s.

It is possible by little hack, but datetimes are conveterted to objects:

```
df = df.astype(object).mask(df.isna(), np.nan)
print (df)
   ORD                      Date1                      Date2
0  717  2020-03-04 00:00:00+00:00  2020-03-04 00:00:00+00:00
1  722                        NaN  2020-03-15 00:00:00+00:00
2  719  2020-05-14 00:00:00+00:00                        NaN

print (df.dtypes)
ORD      object
Date1    object
Date2    object
dtype: object
```

EDIT: If converted datetimes to strings also missing values `NaT` are strings. So for replace them to `NaN`s use:

```
df = df.mask(df == 'NaT', np.nan)
```

Or:

```
df = df.replace('NaT', np.nan)
```

Comment: @jerzael, I tried above mentioned code, It still remains as `NaT`

Comment: @aeapen - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrsel,'0.24.2'

Comment: @aeapen - I test it in `pandas 0.25.1`